# Why is the 'view' property of UIViewController not optional in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift

I noticed that the `view` property of `UIViewController` isn't of type `UIView?` but `UIView` instead (i.e not optional). Why is that? Aren't UIViewController's views supposed to be `nil` when not loaded yet?

The offical documentation states the following:

> The view stored in this property represents the root view for the view controller's view hierarchy. 
>       The default value of this property is nil.
>       ....
>       The UIViewController class can automatically set this property to nil during low-memory conditions and also when the view controller itself is finally released.

From my understanding of Swift optionals, it seems that `view` should be declared as `var view: UIView?` since it may be `nil` at some point. Apple seems to state the opposite, can you explain my why?

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `view` is a lazy property (but not using the `lazy` modifier) - in fact if you read the inline comment (cmd+click on the view property to open the source) it says:

> The getter first invokes [self loadView] if the view hasn't been set yet. Subclasses must call super if they override the setter or getter.

and about `loadView()`:

> This is where subclasses should create their custom view hierarchy if they aren't using a nib. Should never be called directly.

I presume that:

- the standard implementation creates an empty view if it is not instantiated otherwise
- it is backed by an optional variable (not publicly accessible)
- in case of low memory conditions, the backing variable is set to nil, releasing the view instance
- if you try to access the property when the backing variable is nil, it creates a new instance

so its implementation should be conceptually similar to:

```
private var _view: UIView?

var view: UIView {
    if _view == nil {
        loadView()
    }
    return _view!
}

func loadView() {
    if _view == nil {
        // _view = something()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I was about to ask you to write an implementation your theory with code, but you did it before I got the chance. Thank you.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `var _view: UIView?` be marked as `private`?

Answer (score 0):

The property is technically not nil. It initialises the view when the property is accessed first time. It is called [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading). That means, when you access the property you are guaranteed to receive a value. I think the documentation for this property is misleading if not even incorrect.